# Checking for specific user that has joined a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## **I am trying to play an mp3 file when a specific user is moved to the afk voice channel.**

In discord.py rewrite:

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
user = bot.get_user("my user id")
if after.afk and user == True:
    channel = bot.get_channel("the id of the channel I want the bot to connect to")
    voice = await channel.connect()
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('directory of mp3 file'))
    await asyncio.sleep(7)
    await voice.disconnect()
```

### **The Problem**

It all works until I try to specify the user in the if statement:
`user == True`

However, once I include this requirement it stops working.

### **What I've tried**

I have tried to give the user object an attribute, such as `user.connect == True` and `user.joined == True` etc... but no luck.

### **The goal**

In it's perfected form, I would be able to specify not only what user that is required to join the afk channel for the event to work, but also get the channel id of another user so that the bot can connect to that channel:

`channel = bot.get_channel("the id the channel that a specified user is in")`

### **EDIT:**

Based on Diggy's answer I have changed the if statement to look like this:

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if member.id == 'my user id' and cur.afk:
            channel = bot.get_channel('the channel id for the bot to connect to')
            voice = await channel.connect()
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('dir of mp3 file'))
            await asyncio.sleep(7)
            await voice.disconnect()
    else:
            pass
```

However it also plays the audio once I leave the channel.

I tried to specify that it would not play once I leave the channel by using `if member.id == 'my user id' and cur.afk and not prev.afk` but it still plays when I leave.

### **Experimental Solution:**

Okay so I thought of making it so the bot only joins the previous channel and so once I leave the afk channel it plays it in that which isn't a problem. This has allowed it to work and play in the channel previous to the afk one which is great but it's not perfect. It shouldn't need to join the afk channel:

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if member.id == 'my user id' and cur.afk:
            prevchannel = prev.channel.id
            channel = bot.get_channel(prevchannel)
            voice = await channel.connect()
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('dir to mp3 file'))
            await asyncio.sleep('duration of mp3 file')
            await voice.disconnect()
    else:
            pass
```

I thought that an elif might work such as:

```
elif prev.afk is not None and cur.afk is None:
    pass
```

but it pretty much just ignores it.

-The `prev` and `cur` args sometimes don't work too so I have to switch back to `before` and `after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is as follows:

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if member.id == your_user_id and cur.afk and not prev.afk:
        voice = await member.voice.channel.connect()
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('directory of mp3 file'))
        await asyncio.sleep(7)
        await voice.disconnect()
```

Comment: Okay so I have edited it based on the member id option in the if statement you provided and it worked. However once I leave the afk channel it also plays the audio. I have edited the post if you need reference.

Comment: @ChonkyWonky Sorry for the late reply. Just edited my answer: `and cur.afk and not prev.afk` checks if you weren't in an afk channel before, hopefully stopping it from joining when you leave the AFK channel

Comment: Yeah I tried something similar like `prev.afk is not None` and your method but it still joins the channel again after I leave. I'm starting to think that `on_voice_state_update` is only for both joining and leaving but I checked the api and it seemed fine. So I really don't know what is wrong.

Comment: `is not None` unfortunately won't work, as `.afk` returns a boolean, so you'll have to use `and not prev.afk`. I'll test it some more in a bit and get back to you.

Comment: I thought of a mediocre solution which was to make the bot join the previous channel which means that when I leave afk it joins that and not a voice channel. But it's a bit makeshift. I edited the post in case you want to see what I did.

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you're trying to do. Maybe give something like this a go: `elif cur.afk and not prev.afk` - It seems to work for me, it doesn't trigger when I leave the AFK channel

Comment: I have just tried this and it's pretty broken. now when I leave the afk channel it seems to want to join the first channel it can. I'm beginning to wonder if this is frying my raspberry pi, I even put a heatsink on it to prevent it heating up too much lol (discord.py on rasp pi)

Comment: That does sound really odd, and from the logic of the code, it shouldn't be doing that. Sorry to be a pain, but could you paste in the code you're currently using for the event into [hastebin](https://hastebin.com) so I can see what it's doing?

Comment: Don't worry man your helping a lot. https://hastebin.com/iqozuyeyel.py I pasted as is (user id and dir to file)

Comment: Ahh, I see the issue. The `after.afk and not before.afk` should be in the same if statement as the one checking your user id! Sorry, I didn't make it clear, that's my fault. Here's what it should be looking like: `if member.id == 383379982312800257 and after.afk and not before.afk:`

Comment: Haha somehow that works. I thought I had done that originally but somehow it didn't work. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you got it working :) Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In discordpy, you could check the users in a channel and get a list returned to you. Once you get that list, you're able to check if the user in question is in the list of users, so something like the code below is *probably* what you're looking for

```
def user_check(userid, channelid):
    user = bot.get_user(userid)
    channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
    if user in channel.members:
        return true
```